# LaTeX change topmargin for a single page

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins

For a single page the `topmargin` should be changed.
I tried `\newgeometry` but this brings a forced pagebreak with it. `\vspace` does not change the `topmargin`, it only adjusts the height of the second paragrpah of the page.

Is there a way to change the `topmargin` of a single page without a `\pagebreak`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the main problem is that you need a place on the *previous* page to change it and a place on the *current* page to reset it. You can e.g. change `\topmargin` or `\topskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant

HERE \advance\topmargin by 3cm \enlargethispage{-3cm}

\kant[1-4]

AND HERE \advance\topmargin by -3cm

\kant[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant

HERE \topskip=3cm 

\kant[1-4]

AND HERE \topskip=10pt

\kant[1-4]
\end{document}
```